# How do I flag a developer story for moderator attention?

Tags: support, flags, developer-story, spam

I have just seen a developer story that was pure spam. It was just publishing links to a fake movie site.

So, how do I flag a developer story for moderator attention?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Flag one of the user's posts.

If the user has no posts or you are unable to locate the user's profile, flag one of your own posts and include a link to the offending Developer Story.

Comment: Although that gets the job done, I think there should be a direct way of doing it.

Comment: @holydragon There is a [feature-request for that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392506/215552) please do upvote it if you feel it is helpful.