# No option to report Stack Overflow Developer Story pages

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I noticed a couple of Stack Overflow Developer Story pages which offer links to illegal torrents for the purpose of piracy. Here are the links:

https://stackoverflow.com/story/download-commando-3-2019-full-movie-magnet-link-torrent

https://stackoverflow.com/story/download-commando-3-full-movie-free-filmywap-hindi-hd-720p-free-watch-online

There is no option to report the story. Also, there is no link to the user's profile from the story page. If there would have been a link back to the user's profile, then anyone can go to their profile and report it.

Comment: This has been going on for several months now... Hopefully SE will make it easier to combat this

Comment: I poofed both of those users. (Moderators can link from the CV to the associated user profile.) We've been seeing this type of spam in CVs quite a lot recently. I alerted the team and requisitioned bigger guns a few days ago. In the meantime, please just continue flagging these as suggested in the duplicate: pick a post (any one will do), flag for moderator attention, and include a link to the spam CV.

Comment: ...and they got reincarnated after being poofed, so I tried something new. Hope this works to stop the reincarnation. Maybe we need to consult a priest.

Comment: @CodyGray I would love to know what new thing you tried? I see that the first story is 404 while the second one joined back today.

Comment: I suspended the user for a year *before* destroying them, the idea being that any attempt to recreate the destroyed account would have the system automatically suspend the account before they could start spamming. I guess it didn't work...

Comment: @CodyGray they keep coming back.

Comment: I noticed. Not a lot I can do about that, other than keep playing Whack-a-Mole. There are bugs in the Jobs system surrounding this; they're being looked into.

Comment: I think they are using Stack Overflow because of Google indexes Stack Overflow very frequently and these pages get higher rank in the searches. It takes less than a minute to be on the top of Google searches.