# Spam redirection in Stack Overflow profiles

Tags: discussion, feature-request, spam

I was searching for online streaming of a newly released movie, and the first result came from Stack Overflow. Seeing the logo my eyes clicked to it and I opened it and found spam content in the user profile.

I then searched multiple keywords and out of 10, the Stack Overflow was mentioned in 6 results.

I know if we delete the user profile then another will pop up.

Stack Overflow has never stopped anyone from creating an account and asking question, but couldn't we hold the URL in profiles for moderation like we do with reviews, flags, edits and until users will certain privilege approve the URL they are not shown in profile??

I would like to hear community thoughts on this. I love Stack Overflow as 40 percent of my day is spent here, and every time I see Stack Overflow and even the icon of it my eyes click.

There are multiple spam profiles which I found and some of them are:

https://stackoverflow.com/story/download-cats-full-movie-filmywap-hindi-hd-720p-free-watch-online

https://stackoverflow.com/cv/watch-the-body-2019-full-movie-online-free

https://stackoverflow.com/story/watch-online-dabangg-3-2019-hd-full-movie-online-free-hd-streaming-download

Comment: This is also a reported problem in [developer stories](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390293/10871073) and users' posted *Curriculum Vitae*.

Comment: I wish it could be limited to *Curriculum Vitae* but it has now creeped to user description, users website URL and so on.. The best way IMO is to keep it pending before making it public until a rep user approve it, just like **edits** , **flags** .

Comment: On the regular sites new posts are scanned for spam by [Smokey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259362/why-does-stack-exchange-run-a-school-for-smoke-detectors). Unfortunately Jobs doesn't have an API so it is not something the community and Smokey can assist with easily, except stumbling on them and then flag for a mod.